# Unable to load assembly. Ensure that the file is a valid .Net Framework assembly

Tags: winforms, inheritance, compact-framework, assembly-resolution

I have an issue in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 developing a Smart Device Solution with .NET CF 3.5.

The main project is Smart Device Application Project (normal executable for smart devices - WinCE).

This project is referenced to Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms assembly [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvzKi.png).

Now, if I try to [add a new item to the application project and choose the item to be an inherited form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lga0.png) , VS pops up an error that the assembly  [is not a valid .NET project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mthr6.png).

But dialog with all forms in main project is still shown.

This EXE is also SDAP executable (WinCE device). But this EXE has never been referenced to and more - it is exluded from Build all process.

This warning/error message has been never shown before.

What options should I check to solve this problem?

Comment: Now yet [another message](http://i.imgur.com/6lF2ejY.png): Warning: No build assemblies contain components to inherit from.
Buidl the current application, or click Browse and select previously built  assembly from another application.

Comment: Hmm... I have started Visual Studio 2008 with following parameter:  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /log "C:\...\VS 2008 Studio Log.txt" and all  works perfectly: designers are loaded quickly Adding Inherited Form also works properly

Comment: Log file: https://gist.github.com/hellboy81/bb7a465a49aa0f1a5758